# An "Any" option for HTML dropdown forms that can search a SQL database?

Tags: php, sql

I am creating a search form that uses multiple forms to get matching results from a database that contains meat packaging information. I want eventually for users to be able to use forms to search for the width, length, type, shape and description of a package. With only the matching results to be displayed.

Currently I have 3 dropdown boxes and all work and find matching results. Unfortunately they seem to completely override the other form terms (another problem), but I want to add in a "Any" function so users can search for anything without having to give a specific search for all the dropdown boxes everytime limiting the amount of results that will appear.

HTML code:

```
    <body>


    <form action="form3.php" method="post"> 
    <label for ="toolcode">Toolcode: </label> 
    <input type="text" name="term" /><br />
    <label for ="delyncode">Delyn code: </label>
    <input type="text" name="term" /><br />
    <label for ="description">Description: </label>
    <input type="text" name="term" /><br />
    <label for ="traysize">Traysize: </label>
    <input type="text" name="term" /> <br />
    <label for ="trayheight">Trayheight: </label>
    <input type="text" name="term" /> <br /> 
    <label for ="traywidth">Traywidth: </label>
    <input type="text" name="term" /> <br />
    <label for ="traydepth">Traydepth: </label>
    <input type="text" name="term" /> <br />

         <label for="trayrange">Trayrange: </label>
                <select name="trayrange">
                    <option value="Other">--Any--</option>
                    <option value="BBQ">BBQ</option>
                    <option value="Dessert">Dessert</option>
                    <option value="Display">Display</option>
                    <option value="Meat">Meat</option>   
                    <option value="Microwave">Microwave</option>
                    <option value="Party">Party</option>
                    <option value="Salad/Wet Pasta">Salad/Wet Pasta</option>
                    <option value="Snacks">Snacks</option>
                    <option value="Standard">Standard</option>
                </select>

        <label for ="traytype">Traytype: </label> 
                <select name="traytype">
                    <option value="Other">--Any--</option>
                    <option value="Open">Open</option>
                    <option value="Cavitised">Cavitised</option>
                    <option value="Lid">Lid</option>
                    <option value="Tray">Tray</option>
                    <option value="Coallition">Coallition</option>
                    <option value="Bowl">Bowl</option>
                    <option value="Hinge pack">Open</option>
                    <option value="Pot">Pot</option>
                    <option value="Base & Lid">Base and Lid</option>
                    <option value="Rectangular">Rectangular</option>
                    <option value="Specalist">Specialist</option>
                </select><br />

        <label for="trayshape">Trayshape: </label>
                <select name="trayshape">
                    <option value="Other">--Any--</option>
                    <option value="Rectangular">Rectangular</option>
                    <option value="Oval">Oval</option>
                    <option value="Square">Square</option>
                    <option value="Insert">Insert</option>
                    <option value="Round">Round</option>
                    <option value="Open">Open</option>
                </select><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
    </form> 

      </body>
```

The current "Any" option i have above was just a test. It doesn't work, no results get displayed.

PHP code:

```
       <body>

        <?php
            $con = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "");
                   mysql_select_db ("delyn_db", $con);

            if (!$con)
                { 
                    die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
                }

            $varRange = $_POST['trayrange'];
            $varType = $_POST['traytype'];
            $varShape = $_POST['trayshape'];
            $term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['term']);    

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM delyn WHERE toolcode LIKE '%".$term."%' AND delyncode LIKE
                   '%".$term."%' AND description LIKE '%".$term."%' AND traysize LIKE
                   '%".$term."%' AND trayheight LIKE '%".$term."%' AND traywidth LIKE
                   '%".$term."%' AND traydepth LIKE '%".$term."%' AND trayrange LIKE
                   '%".$varRange."%' AND traytype LIKE '%".$varType."%' AND trayshape LIKE
                   '%".$varShape."%' ";


            $r_query = mysql_query($sql);


        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query))
                    { 
               echo '<br /> Delyn code:  ' .$row['delyncode']; 
           echo '<br /> Tool Code:   '.$row['toolcode'];
           echo '<br /> Description: '.$row['description']; 
           echo '<br /> Tray range   '.$row['trayrange']; 
           echo '<br /> Tray type:   '.$row['traytype'];
           echo '<br /> Tray size:   '.$row['traysize']; 
           echo '<br /> Tray height: '.$row['trayheight']; 
           echo '<br /> Tray width:  '.$row['traywidth']; 
           echo '<br /> Tray depth:  '.$row['traydepth'];
           echo '<br /> Tray shape:  '.$row['trayshape'] . '<br />' . '<br />'; ;  
                    }


        ?>
            </body>
```

What would I need to add to allow the users to search allowing for any "tray range", "trayshape" and "traytype". This in theory should display results that match the forms that have info entered.

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use different names for different text-fields otherwise they will be overwritten i.e the last text got preferred at server side you will get tray width only because its the last one with name term

Comment: I have managed to fix the override problem, now the search returns results that are related to the users choices. I can't quite figure out how to make the "Any" search on dropdowns work, I managed to make it so that when users clicked Any it returned only searches with the keywords in the other forms. But that returned all results :(

Comment: instead of AND in Query use OR that will check any option by user

Comment: i have experimented with each of them, i can't quite get it right, it is just making the whole database be displayed.

Comment: i can't get it when user select any in trayshape select boxe it should dispaly tray's of all types by taking remaining all choices in to account will the user have to enter all the text box options or not

Comment: Overall the search should be able to handle users being really detailed with their searches and only display a small amount of results. Or it should handle very broad searches that will display lots of results (such as having Any searches in the dropboxes).

Comment: AND seems to work but you have to be specific with your searches. OR doesn't work with it displaying all of the database results.

Comment: yeah i came to know that by seeing your goal see my second answer